# Routing through 2 interfaces

Tags: networking, iptables, routing

VPS A with KVM virtualization with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

VPN server: 10.29.0.0/24

VPS B with KVM virtualization with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
VPN client from VPS A: 10.29.0.19
VPN server: 10.8.0.0/24

I don't control VPS A, and as VPN server allow communications between VPN clients.

From the command line of VPS B itself I can ping all the clients of the VPN server at VPS A.

```
root@vpsB:~# ping 10.29.0.1
PING 10.29.0.1 (10.29.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.29.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3.09 ms
64 bytes from 10.29.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=3.10 ms
^C
--- 10.29.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.091/3.094/3.097/0.003 ms
root@vpsB:~# ping 10.29.0.5
PING 10.29.0.5 (10.29.0.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.29.0.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=59.8 ms
64 bytes from 10.29.0.5: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=60.0 ms
^C
--- 10.29.0.5 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 59.761/59.877/59.994/0.116 ms
```

```
root@vpsB:~# ip address show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:3c:a2:85:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 217.XXX.XXX.111/24 brd 217.XXX.XXX.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    
3: tun1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.8.0.1/24 brd 10.8.0.255 scope global tun1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    
4: tun3: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.29.0.19/24 brd 10.29.0.255 scope global tun3
```

```
root@vpsB:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         217.XXX.XXX.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun1
10.29.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun3
217.XXX.XXX.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

```
root@vpsB:~# iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

What do I need to do in order to ping from 10.8.0.0/24 to 10.29.0.0/24?

Comment: Interesting question. Sounds like you are trying to integrate two VPN networks. I believe you own VPS-B (10.8.0.0/24) that in turn is a VPN server. I believe you want clients to connect to VPS-B VPN server, and have their traffic routed to the next VPN server (VPS-A). You do not own VPS-A (10.29.0.0/24). Kindly confirm if VPS-A allows client-to-client (c2c) communications. Your ping command did not confirm c2c because you pinged the VPN server itself

Comment: yes, VPS A allow commnications betweens clients. I made a ping to 10.29.0.5
PING 10.29.0.5 (10.29.0.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.29.0.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=59.8 ms
 and worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iptables` rules are processed from top to bottom. From `VPS-B` (that you own), you already have existing NAT rules that you must re-arrange. In order to re-arrange the NAT rules, you must copy the existing ones to a text editor, then delete the existing rules. Then re-add the NAT rules in the right order.

The procedure goes like this:

To view existing NAT chain rules (before deletion):

```
sudo iptables -t nat -L -n --line-numbers
```

Save the rules to a text editor

To delete existing NAT rules:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING 1
```

Repeat above command till all NAT rules are removed.
Then re-add the NAT rules.

Make sure the following rule goes first (then rest of NAT rules will follow):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 10.29.0.0/24 -o tun3 -j MASQUERADE
```

Make sure the rules are in right order:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -L -n --line-numbers
```

VPS-B is already interconnecting `10.8.0.0/24` and `10.29.0.0/24`, therefore no further route statements are required on this server.

From the VPN clients that are using VPS-B as their VPN server, tell them to use the VPN server (`10.8.0.1`) as the next hop to subnet `10.29.0.0/24`

```
sudo ip route add 10.29.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.1
```

If all works well, consider saving the iptables rules on VPS-B server. The guide is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119393/how-to-save-rules-of-the-iptables)

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: I have updated the answer. I have tested and its working from side. Thanks for your question. I have learned something new

Comment: many many many thanks!!!!!!!!!